# Using importlib, how can you import variables from a .py file and declare them locally

Tags: python, python-importlib

I am trying to simulate the

```
from module import *
```

but using the importlib module

What I have now is:

```
v = importlib.import_module(load_list[0])
```

but then I have to access all variables using v.xxx